# Can't change color on an image drawing canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, canvas, html5-canvas

I have created an image drawing canvas but the drawing color can't change. maybe it's javascript set color but can't find. if anyone knows please help me. this is the demo link

http://affibe.com/erevo/

**HTML Code:**
`

```
<html class="gr__adsterra_com">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/pixi.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/animationFrame.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/nodes.js"></script>
<style>body{margin: 0; background-color: transparent;}</style>
</head>
<body data-gr-c-s-loaded="true">
    <header> 
    <script>lowPerformance=function (){var ua=navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase(); if (ua.indexOf("iphone") !=-1 || ua.indexOf("mobile") !=-1) return true; if ($(window).width()==0) return; return ($(window).width() <=480) ? true : false;}; var ie=false; var w=window, d=document, documentElement=d.documentElement, body=d.getElementsByTagName('body')[0], height=w.innerHeight|| documentElement.clientHeight|| body.clientHeight; if (navigator.appName=='Microsoft Internet Explorer') ie=true; Nodes.multipleInit([{"post_name": "AFFIBE", "drawnImage": (height>860)?"http:\/\/affibe.com\/erevo\/images\/main\/logo_header_er.png":"http:\/\/affibe.com\/erevo\/images\/main\/logo_header_er.png", "linkTitle": "AFFIBE", "particleDensity": ie?"11":"7", "particleWidth": "0.5", "particleHeight": "0.5"}]); </script>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

**pixi.min.js:**
http://affibe.com/erevo/js/pixi.min.js

**animationFrame.js**

```
!function(){for(var n=0,i=["ms","moz","webkit","o"],e=0;e<i.length&&!window.requestAnimationFrame;++e)window.requestAnimationFrame=window[i[e]+"RequestAnimationFrame"],window.cancelAnimationFrame=window[i[e]+"CancelAnimationFrame"]||window[i[e]+"CancelRequestAnimationFrame"];window.requestAnimationFrame||(window.requestAnimationFrame=function(i){var e=(new Date).getTime(),a=Math.max(0,16-(e-n)),o=window.setTimeout(function(){i(e+a)},a);return n=e+a,o}),window.cancelAnimationFrame||(window.cancelAnimationFrame=function(n){clearTimeout(n)})}();
```

Comment: Please provide your code directly in the question, not as a link elsewhere.

Comment: I upload the full code please help me

Answer (score 0):

if i understand it the follow code help to you

```
var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx= c.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle="#66bfff";
```

for example

```js
var c   = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "#f00";
ctx.fillRect(40, 40, 40, 40);
```

```css
#canvas{
    border: 2px solid #333;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i put this code but not working I see this i.fillStyle="#f00" on the pixi.min.js: http://prntscr.com/k1vzr2 change this color but not change the color?

Comment: I snippet the code please run code snippet and if not , so i don't  understand your purpose